# Local autologon-User should not be try to logon on Domain

Tags: domain

Setting: Win 10 LTSC (1809,21H2,22H2)
Local User has setup to autologon on local machine with netplwiz.(Kinda Kios-kmode without using Kiosk-mode()
Works perfect for us and need to stay this way.

Now we transfered a bunch of Clients in a Domain, the local autologon must stay.
Suddenly the local autologin user try to login on the domain as well.
Our CS-Team send us this as info "4625 (User logon with misspelled or bad user account)"

Q
how to stop the local user from trying the domain-logon?
any hints?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to cashed domain login information. You could try specifying the domain in netplwiz by using the syntax `local\Username` or `HOSTNAME\Username` in the Username field.

Alternatively create / adjust the string (REG_SZ) value in the registry:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultDomainName`

Set the value to your machines HOSTNAME

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/turn-on-automatic-logon

Comment: Thank you for the hint. i already tried this but the local user still try to logon in the Domain.